# What is the Best way to kill database Routine(repeated) work in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

What is the Best way to kill database Routine(repeated) work in php ,  i work daily with php & mysql through pdo and other libs , but i feel i repeat myself over and over ADD , DELETE , UPDATE , especially in admin panel , every task require these operations , its kill the programming enjoyment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out an Object Relational Mapper (ORM) such as [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/). ORM's take care of all the SQL and let you focus on maintaining your data as a set of objects you can add, query, modify and save.

Comment: so how it will help me ?? can you clarify ?

Comment: Doctrine has a [comprehensive introduction to ORM and the problems it solves](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/introduction/en).